# Find and replace STRING3 when it occurs between STRING1 and STRING2

Tags: sed

I have a file that contains several lines of text like this:

`aaa 12`
`bbb 23`
`ccc 34`
`ddd 45`
`eee 56`
`ccc 67`

I'm essentially trying to replace "ccc" (STRING3) with "xxx", but only when "ccc" occurs between "aaa" (STRING1) and "ddd" (STRING2). So the output would look like:

`aaa 12`
`bbb 23`
`xxx 34`
`ddd 45`
`eee 56`
`ccc 67`

Ideally looking for a solution that uses `sed`

I've tried several `sed` commands but everything I found replaces all text between STRING1 and STRING2. I'm only looking to replace a specific string between two outer strings.

Comment: Why not simply `sed '/aaa/,/ddd/s/ccc/xxx/' file` ?

Comment: Please post what you've tried so we can explain what you did wrong.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin This works, thanks! First time using sed didn't realize the solution was so simple. The string I want to replace with has a "/" in it, how would I incorporate that? I've tried `sed '/aaa/,/ddd/s/ccc/xxx//' file` but that errors.

Comment: @hsid `sed '/aaa/,/ddd/s/ccc/xxx\//' file`

Comment: Or to avoid escaping, use a character than slash as the delimiter, eg: `sed '#aaa#,#ddd#s#ccc#xxx/#' file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^aaa/{:a;N;/^ddd/M!ba;s/^ccc/xxx/mg}' file
```

Gather up lines between a line starting `aaa` and ending `ccc`.

Replace all lines in the collection starting with `ccc` with `xxx`.

N.B. The use of the flags `M` and `m` in the matching and substitution commands, which allow the `^` to represent the start of line in a multiline string in the pattern space.